# Symfony Doctrine createQuery

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Suppose I have an entity "events" and "users". Users entity is the owing side of a ManyToMany relation to events. My user can book an event which works fine. Now I try to fetch all events and a "identifier" if a user has booked the event. I try to add the user id to the array if the user has booked. Now I try to get these in one query

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $this->token = $tokenStorage->getToken();
        $user = $this->token->getUser()->getId();
        

       $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT e, u.id FROM App\Entity\Events e LEFT JOIN e.users u WITH u.id = :id WHERE e.date >= :dateFirstDay and e.date <= :dateLastDay and e.date > :dateNow ")
        ->setParameter('dateFirstDay',$dateStartDay->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->setParameter('dateLastDay',$dateEndDay->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->setParameter('dateNow',$now->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->setParameter('id', $user);
        $events = $query->getArrayResult();
    
        return new JsonResponse($events);
```

This gives me the booked event twice. One with id "null" and the other with the (right) user id. How can I avoid to get the event with id "null"? I tried with "GROUP BY e" but that don't work.
Here is my postman output:

```
    {
        "0": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Event 1 ",
            "date": {
                "date": "2021-03-10 15:32:37.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
            },
            "description": "Beschreibungstext",
            "duration": "45"
        },
        "id": null
    },
    {
        "0": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Event 1 ",
            "date": {
                "date": "2021-03-10 15:32:37.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
            },
            "description": "Beschreibungstext",
            "duration": "45"
        },
        "id": 4
    },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try adding "AND e.users IS NOT NULL"

anyway I suggest you to consider alternative ways to do this query if you can; think that it's common that a query to a Repository (eg. "Events") should return only instances of Events entity, and not "Events entity + user id" as you are doing with ""SELECT e, u.id"

you could do just just "SELECT e", you will have a list of Events, and then on each entity you should be able to call "$even->getUsers()" if I understood well

Comment: i want to get the null id if the event isnt booked. Why it should return only the events? There is a ManyToMany relation between user and event. Its mabye a security problem if i return the whole user object. In production i would use another ident, not the row id but this is just a training project ;)

Comment: because returning hybrid results can lead to unexpected behaviors, as the one you are exposing

Comment: consider this sentence: "When you query for a particular type of object, you always use what’s known as its “repository”. You can think of a repository as a PHP class whose only job is to help you fetch entities of a certain class." https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database

Comment: the idea is that from EventsRepository you obtain only array (or single entities) which are instance of Events. If you are interested to the Users you should interrogate UsersRepository